# What is the exact difference between setMinimumFetchIntervalInSeconds and fetch(long minimumFetchIntervalInSeconds)

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-remote-config

There are two `minimumFetchIntervalInSeconds`es in [FirebaseRemoteConfig](https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config/get-started?platform=android).

1. [`FirebaseRemoteConfigSettings.Builder.setMinimumFetchIntervalInSeconds(long duration)`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/firebase/remoteconfig/FirebaseRemoteConfigSettings.Builder?hl=ja#setMinimumFetchIntervalInSeconds(long))
2. [`FirebaseRemoteConfig.fetch(long minimumFetchIntervalInSeconds)`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/firebase/remoteconfig/FirebaseRemoteConfig?hl=ja#fetch(long))

What is the exact difference between them other than the priorities explained in the [document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config/get-started?platform=android#throttling)? Should I use both of them or to use either one of them is sufficient?

```
mFirebaseRemoteConfig = FirebaseRemoteConfig.getInstance();

FirebaseRemoteConfigSettings configSettings = new FirebaseRemoteConfigSettings
        .Builder()
        .setMinimumFetchIntervalInSeconds(mCacheExpiration) // <-- (1)
        .build();
mFirebaseRemoteConfig.setConfigSettingsAsync(configSettings);

mFirebaseRemoteConfig.fetch(mCacheExpiration); // <-- (2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you use `setMinimumFetchIntervalInSeconds` you can later just call `mFirebaseRemoteConfig.fetch()` without specificying an expiration. It will then use the one you specified before. See also [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/remoteconfig/FirebaseRemoteConfig)

> fetch(long minimumFetchIntervalInSeconds)
>
> Starts fetching configs, adhering to the specified minimum fetch interval.
>
> fetch()
>
> Starts fetching configs, adhering to the default minimum fetch
> interval.

And notice that [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/remoteconfig/FirebaseRemoteConfig#fetch()) it does in fact say that

> The default minimum fetch interval can be set with FirebaseRemoteConfigSettings.Builder#setMinimumFetchIntervalInSeconds(long)

Comment: Thank you :) But I would rather know and understand more internal difference.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. I think I explained that also. If you want the exact implementation you can always dig through the source code here for example https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/tree/master/firebase-config/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/remoteconfig

Comment: Thank you! That GitHub is what I want (I didn't know that). So, I have figured out that `setMinimumFetchIntervalInSeconds` can persists because it saves in a SharedPreferences file.